# Complex python dictionary sort by value

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dictionary with ints for keys, and strings for values. I need to to sort by the strings, so that when I go dict.values() I get the sorted list.

The strings are values like this: 45_12_something_23

I need to sort numbers as numbers and strings as strings. A given row is guaranteed to be either a string or a number (not a mixture).

Whats a good way to do this in python? Performance isnt an issue.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have order...

Comment: If you want a sorted list of keys: write your own sorting method splitting the keys into parts, normalize it and provide it as sortable key. Check out the sorted() documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your dictionary to a list of (key,value) pairs.  Sort them however you'd like.  (Or is that your question - how to do that?)  Then insert the sorted (key,value) pairs into a [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which will remember the insertion order and use the same order when iterating.

Note that you can't modify the `dict` you already have, this will make a new `dict` with the properties you want.

Comment: Yeah, thats the approach I've been taking - so I've got a 2 dimensional list now, with my string broken up into another list of the actual values. How do I use sorted() to properly sort this new 2D list?

Comment: Cool, so I think sorted(list, key=itemgetter(i)) will give me what I'm after. Cheers Keith!

Comment: FYI, python automatically sorts an n-dimensional list appropriately. Pretty handy!